# Jenkins copy directories/files in a build

Tags: build, jenkins

I am trying to copy files out to a network directory during a build, and I keep getting a " No such file or directory" error message.

Copying to local drive works fine:

```
cp -Rf c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/target
```

The following all throw the same message:

```
cp -Rf c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src H:/some_dir

cp -Rf c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src H:\some_dir

cp -Rf c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src //Hubbell/MISGenl/some_dir

cd c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src
rsync -avuzb //Hubbell/MISGenl/Projects/Tronweb/TronwebBuilds/test/ora/sql/

cp -Rf c:/Jenkins/deployments/TW_ISSUE_A/src /cygdrive/h/some_dir
```

I've even created a shell script to call from Jenkins, but I continue to receive that message.

```
#!/bin/bash

url="http://as-test02:8080/job/TW_ISSUE_A_BUILD/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bui
ld-TW_ISSUE_A_BUILD.tar";

remote_stage_dir="/cygdrive/h/some_dir"

#fetch the artifacts

(cd "$remote_stage_dir" && wget "$url" && tar xvf build-TW_ISSUE_A_BUILD.tar dat
 java ora && rm -rf *.tar && cp -r ./ora/* ../INTEGRATION)
```

Is there any way to copy files out to a mapped drive on the build machine?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess the mapped drive isn't available in the services context, or that the user executing Jenkins doesn't have access to it. What user is Jenkins running as?

**Edit:**
I think your problem has two aspects:

1. The user running the Jenkins service isn't allowed to connect to the network.
2. `h:` isn't known to the user.

If you haven't modified it, the service is most likely running under the [LocalSystem account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can modify this by running `services.msc` (or navigate to services via the Windows control panel) and locating the `jenkins` service. This should resolve the first problem.

The second problem can be resolved by using [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) paths (as you tried above) instead of network drives.

The [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/) has an article about problems like this: [My software builds on my computer but not on Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+software+builds+on+my+computer+but+not+on+Jenkins)

Comment: Jenkins is running on a VM server - I (trandal) was logged in when the service was started.    I didn't say it above, but I can use any/all commands (and run the script) when I'm on the server.   I'm going to go look it up - not sure what you mean by "services context"

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!  I updated Jenkins to run under a named user, as well as mapped a drive per the Jenkins wiki link.  Thank you again!!