# Why does my build hang when using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build

I have a build which hangs in Jenkins. I have deconstructed the build down to a single windows command call, a directory change and a couple of echoes in an effort to isolate the problem. It would appear that the problem lies with a single call to a program executable (now the only call in my build). The build calls the program & then hangs for 30+ minutes (I cancel the build after this time) when it should take less than 1 second. Ordinarily I would be inclined to blame the executable or my misuse thereof, but for the fact that the same call (quite literally copied & pasted) in an ordinary command prompt works perfectly fine. Further muddying the waters is my knowledge of the fact that the build I'm trying implement is working just fine on another Jenkins server I know of, executable and all, and has never had an issue. I'm sorry I can't provide details on the executable in question but it's sensitive information. It may very well be the case that the executable is to blame, but the exact same call in three environments and only one hangs? What do you think?

More info on request.

Comment: It's likely the executable + environment that's to blame. I don't see how anyone on SO can answer this question without more details. Your best bet is to instrument your executable or attach to it with a debugger to see where it is hanging.

Comment: OK, I'm going to assume that the program behaves differently when called from Jenkins rather than the command line (though I don't see why), and I'm also going to assume that the difference is, that the program is not running silently, i.e. it's looking for input or displaying a warning. Now from what I've read elsewhere, Jenkins doesn't deal with any sort of interactivity and the only solution is to kill the build, but what I'm wondering now is, is there some way to time-out a particular build step in a build and then move on to the next build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there I was, waiting for a reply when I decided to click on one of the ["Related" topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794628/1515078) on the right hand side. Lo and behold, there it was, a solution to my problem in answer to a different question. In short it goes like this:

Jenkins is a service. Services (on Windows) have a "Log On" account, of which the default appears to be "Local System". This had the effect of forcing (though I don't know why) my program out of quiet mode and thus hanging the build. Changing the "Log On" account to my own seems to have changed the behavioural relationship between Jenkins and the executable so that it now runs smooth and silent.

Comment: Thanks to @AndersLindahl for indirectly helping me solve my problem.